# Why does this update_post_meta function not delete the custom field itself?

Tags: php, functions, custom-field, metabox

I'm trying to set a meta key value of either "yes" or null with the checkbox so I can select posts using a query that checks if the meta key exists and not use the value of the meta_key. I don't want to add a meta_key to all existing posts, and want the meta_key to be deleted when unchecked.

But `update_post_meta` at the end of this function doesn't delete the meta_key `featured-checkbox` on update. How can I get the function to delete the key?

```
// Featured Post metabox

function prfx_featured_meta() {
    add_meta_box( 'prfx_meta', __( 'Featured Posts', 'prfx-textdomain' ), 'prfx_meta_callback', 'post', 'side', 'high' );
}
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'prfx_featured_meta' );

/**
 * Outputs the content of the meta box
 */

function prfx_meta_callback( $post ) {
    wp_nonce_field( basename( __FILE__ ), 'prfx_nonce' );
    $prfx_stored_meta = get_post_meta( $post->ID );
    ?>

 <p>
    <span class="prfx-row-title"><?php _e( 'Check if this is a featured post: ', 'prfx-textdomain' )?></span>
    <div class="prfx-row-content">
        <label for="featured-checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" name="featured-checkbox" id="featured-checkbox" value="yes" <?php if ( isset ( $prfx_stored_meta['featured-checkbox'] ) ) checked( $prfx_stored_meta['featured-checkbox'][0], 'yes' ); ?> />
            <?php _e( 'Featured Item', 'prfx-textdomain' )?>
        </label>

    </div>
</p>   

    <?php
}

/**
 * Saves the custom meta input
 */
function prfx_meta_save( $post_id ) {

    // Checks save status
    $is_autosave = wp_is_post_autosave( $post_id );
    $is_revision = wp_is_post_revision( $post_id );
    $is_valid_nonce = ( isset( $_POST[ 'prfx_nonce' ] ) && wp_verify_nonce( $_POST[ 'prfx_nonce' ], basename( __FILE__ ) ) ) ? 'true' : 'false';

    // Exits script depending on save status
    if ( $is_autosave || $is_revision || !$is_valid_nonce ) {
        return;
    }

    // Checks for input and sanitizes/saves if needed
    // How do I delete the featured-checkbox key and not update it?
    if( isset( $_POST[ 'featured-checkbox' ] ) ) {
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'featured-checkbox', sanitize_text_field( $_POST[ 'featured-checkbox' ] ) );
    }

}
add_action( 'save_post', 'prfx_meta_save' );
```

**Update 12/22/16: this change works:**

```
// Checks for input and saves - save checked as yes or deletes meta_key if no
if( isset( $_POST[ 'featured-checkbox' ] ) ) {
    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'featured-checkbox', 'yes' );
} else {
        delete_post_meta( $post_id, 'featured-checkbox' );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for `delete_post_meta($post_id, $meta_key, $meta_value);`

> #### Parameters
>
> **$post_id** (integer) (required) The ID of the post from which you will delete a field. Default: None
>
> **$meta_key** (string)
> (required) The key of the field you will delete. Default: None
>
> **$meta_value** (mixed) (optional)
> The value of the field you will delete.
> This is used to differentiate between several fields with the same
> key. If left blank, all fields with the given key will be deleted.
> Default: Empty

Comment: Thanks, you're right; and I added a condiitonal to check if yes, save, if no, delete.